# what data type to put for 9:30 in my mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am almost done with building a php web application for a school system like feature to add classes and display in schdule and students can view schedule and add classes.  My question is i put INT for hours (ex: 9-12)  I want to put 9:30 to 12:00  do I have to change the datatype to VARCHAR in my mysql database

Also, is there a jquery or javascript where it automatically pops out the hours.  For now Im making the user put 9 AM to 12 PM (for example)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`TIME` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) for this

Comment: Yes. Time will even keep track of seconds as well.

Comment: Thanks I will update it in my database later on today, I will post what will happen,  thanks for your help